# remove substring from filename

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have files with name of the form "NAME-xxxxxx.tedx" and I want to remove the "-xxxxxx" part. The x are all digits. 
The regex `"\-[0-9]{1,6}"` matches the substring, but I have no idea how to remove it from the filename.

Any idea how I can do that in the shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the [perl version of the `rename` command](http://man.he.net/man1/rename) installed, you could try:

```
rename 's/-[0-9]+//' *.tedx
```

Demo:

```
[me@home]$ ls
hello-123.tedx  world-23456.tedx
[me@home]$ rename 's/-[0-9]+//' *.tedx
[me@home]$ ls
hello.tedx  world.tedx
```

This command is smart enough to not rename files if it means overwriting an existing file:

```
[me@home]$ ls
hello-123.tedx  world-123.tedx  world-23456.tedx
[me@home]$ rename 's/-[0-9]+//' *.tedx
world-23456.tedx not renamed: world.tedx already exists
[me@home]$ ls
hello.tedx  world-23456.tedx  world.tedx
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo NAME-12345.tedx | sed "s/-[0-9]*//g"
```

will give `NAME.tedx`. So you can use a loop and move the files using `mv` command:

```
for file in *.tedx; do
   newfile=$(echo "$file" | sed "s/-[0-9]*//g")
   mv "$file" $newfile
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use just the shell

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in *-+([0-9]]).tedx; do
    newname=${f%-*}.tedx    # strip off the dash and all following chars
    [[ -f $newname ]] || mv "$f" "$newname"
done
```